# API for olympics?

Tags: api

I am developing a quick and fun little app which will display in a lobby. All it really does is go country to country showing flag, population, etc.... for all countries particapting in this years olympics.

I am reusing code we created for the 2010 olympics, and one of its features was a feed how many medals each country had won (plus a total count on the side). The data was hosted on the offical website, but has since been removed. Its easy to build out this feature, but it makes the app much more interesting if I can get it working

Is there an free API available anywhere which feeds this information?

Comment: Anyone have any info for the 2016 games?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I googled "olympic data feed". The first two results were:

http://odf.olympictech.org/

http://odf.olympictech.org/help.htm

Down the page, I saw this:

http://www.stats.com/olympics.asp

Sounds like they are the official data people for the 2012 olympics.

Comment: A lot of this is describing the schema of the XML is returns, but I haven't found anything there which actually provides the data

Comment: Damn, I was hoping for something free

Comment: Ain't nothing free in this world!

Comment: Seems this is still the service they use for the 2016 games.